# on adding a child layout more than one time using addView() the child layout buttons stops working

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my child xml file(repeat.xml) which i want to add in main xml file

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/divider_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="enter name here"
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="edit"
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_marginTop="160dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="save"
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="button2"
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

this is my main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main"
tools:context="com.example.pawan.recyclerview.Main2Activity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main1"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp">
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my main.java

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    RelativeLayout rl=findViewById(R.id.main1);
//        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.main1);
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.repeat, null);
            rl.addView(child);
        }
        final EditText textView2=findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        textView2.setEnabled(false);
        Button button1=findViewById(R.id.b1);
        Button button2=findViewById(R.id.b2);
        Button button3=findViewById(R.id.b3);
        final TimePicker tp=findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
        tp.setEnabled(false);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView2.setEnabled(false);
                tp.setEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),textView2.getText().toString()+" time is:" +tp.getCurrentHour() + ":" + tp.getCurrentMinute(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

when i do not use the for loop in main.java and direct add child view only once it's working fine. But since i want to add it multiple times and on adding it using for loop multiple times the repeat.xml buttons stops working, thwy does'nt give any feedback i.e they becomes fixed(not clickable) and textview are not editable. Please give a solution for this :)

Comment: use **`Recyclerview`**

Comment: may be layouts are overlapping. use LinearLayout instead RelativeLayout

Comment: @Nilesh please give an example how to do using RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1):

Your main error is here:

```
for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    // add several layouts
}
// findViewById is outside the loop. So, this code will be executed only once and only for one view.
```

`findViewById` does not automatically changes all view with that ID. It just seach and return the first view with that ID. If you have more than one view using the same ID only the first view with that ID will be returned (which is your case because you are inflating same layout several times).

Also, you must find for a View not in the whole screen (since you have several views with same ID). You can search "inside" a specific layout or inside a view...

Instead of:

```
// Search a view inside the whole screen (root layout).
findViewById(R.id.tv2);
```

You can use:

```
// Search a view only inside child
child.findViewById(R.id.b1);
```

You should do something like:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
RelativeLayout rl=findViewById(R.id.main1);
for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.repeat, null);
    rl.addView(child);

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Not that I'm looking for a R.id.tv2 but inside child view... and not in root view
    // Use child.findViewById(R.id.tv2) instead of findViewById(R.id.tv2)

    final EditText textView2 = child.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    textView2.setEnabled(false);

    // SAME HERE
    Button button1 = child.findViewById(R.id.b1);
    Button button2 = child.findViewById(R.id.b2);
    Button button3 = child.findViewById(R.id.b3);
    final TimePicker tp = child.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

    tp.setEnabled(false);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView2.setEnabled(false);
            tp.setEnabled(false);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),textView2.getText().toString()+" time is:" +tp.getCurrentHour() + ":" + tp.getCurrentMinute(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Note that are better ways to what you want such as `ListView`, `RecyclerView` etc... but this is another history.

Comment: but still i am not able to repeat my repeat.xml file multiple, its just displayed one time. Please provide a solution using ListView, RecyclerView as you said for your answer to be accepted